# bash vs sh script different results

Tags: bash, shell, macos-sierra

When I run these lines in my terminal on macOS I get the correct result

```
hex=$(echo -n 'betty' | xxd -p)
echo $hex

6265747479
```

but when I run them in a bash script I get something completely different

```
sh myscript.sh

62657474790a
```

It's like its put a carriage return on the end for some reason. WHY?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please add the output of `cat myscript.sh; sh myscript.sh`

Comment: @Peter: First, it's not a *carriage return*, it is a *line feed*. Secondly, it seems that different shells are involved. In your second example, you provide `sh` as a shell, and we don't know where sh is linked to on your machine. If both are bash shells, they might be different versions (do a `print $BASH_VERSION` in both variants), which implement the `echo` in a different way.

Comment: I'm surprised that `echo -n 'betty'` would produce that output, which appears to be `betty` followed by a newline. I'd expect either `betty` without a newline, or `-n betty` with a newline. What exactly does `sh -c 'echo -n betty'` print, compared to `echo -n betty`? What does `ls -l /bin/sh` say?

Comment: `sh -c 'echo -n betty'` gives me `-n betty` `echo -n betty` gives me `betty` with the next prompt on the same line as betty `ls -l /bin/sh` =>  `-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  630464 29 Apr 10:31 /bin/sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different versions of `echo` do different things when given `-n` as their first argument. Some print it as part of their output, some interpret it as a flag, who knows what's going to happen. According to the [POSIX standard for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), "If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a backslash character, the results are implementation-defined."

The most reliable way to print a string without a linefeed after it is with `printf`. It's slightly more complicated because you have to give it a format string as well as the string you want printed:

```
hex=$(printf "%s" 'betty' | xxd -p)
```

Comment: I see, so even though they are the same command the runtime (sic) can deal with them in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Try `bash` instead of `sh`. As `echo` is a *builtin* command, it depends on the shell how it is executed. For me, the echo from sh does not seem to support `-n`:

```
sh-3.2$ echo -n hello
-n hello
sh-3.2$ echo $(echo -n 'betty' | xxd -p)
2d6e2062657474790a
```